# What is this kind of nested function called

Tags: syntax

I found a call expression which looks like:

```
germany(1)(square)
```

where germany is a function and square is a function

```
def square(x):
return x*x
def argentina(n):
    print(n)
    if n>0:
        return lambda k: k(n+1)
    else:
        return 1/n
def germany(n):
    if n>1:
        print('hallo')
    if argentina(n-2)>=0:
        print('bye')
    return argentina(n+2)
```

I have never seen syntax like this before and was wondering what this is called, and if someone can tell me how it works?
From my understanding germany(1) first executes and then I square germany(1)
In other words:
germany(1)(square)==square(germany(1))

thank you

Comment: `argentina` returns an interesting object, try to figure out what it does.

Comment: depending on the input, argentina returns either a function  or a number?

Comment: Well if it returns a number then it is not so interesting. What happens with the funcgion? What does it do?